# Kotlin Mockito Tests Failing for Exception Handling

Tags: unit-testing, exception, kotlin, mockito-kotlin

I'm trying to write exception handling and tests for said handling in Kotlin, using Mockito. The tests are failing due to the exceptions not being thrown and I can't figure out why. It looks like they should be thrown and I'm stumped.

Here is a sample of the code in question.

```
private fun tryToDoTheThing(workItem: WorkItem, metrics: Metrics) {
    try {
        serviceFacade.doTheThing(workItem.accountId, workItem.name)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        handleException(ex, metrics, workItem)
    }
}

@Throws(DoTheThingFailedException::class)
private fun handleException(ex: Exception, metrics: Metrics, workItem: WorkItem) {
    var message: String
    when (ex) {

        is <other exception cases that are not valid for this question> -> {
            throwTheThingFailedException(message, metrics)
        }

        is RuntimeException -> {
            metrics.addCount(FAULT, 1)
            val cause = ex.cause
            message = "Received exception when attempting to to the thing " +
                    "name=[${workItem.name}], accountId=[${workItem.accountId}]"

            if (cause is HttpFailureException) {
                metrics.addProperty(EXCEPTION, cause!!::class.java.simpleName)
            } else {
                metrics.addProperty(EXCEPTION, ex::class.java.simpleName)
            }
            LOG.info(message)
            throw DoTheThingFailedException(message, ex)
        }
    }
}

@Throws(DoTheThingFailedException::class)
private fun throwAcknowledgeJobFailedException(message: String, metrics: Metrics) {
    LOG.info(message)
    metrics.addCount(ERROR, 1)
    throw DoTheThingFailedException(message)
}
```

And here is the test

```
@Test(expected = RuntimeException::class)
fun handleRuntimeException() {
    // given        
    val errorMessage = "Received exception when attempting to acknowledge name=[name], accountId=[accountId]"

    `when`(serviceFacade.doTheThing(any(), any())).thenThrow(RuntimeException())

    // when (this calls the item that does the thing)
    val runOneIteration = WorkDispatcher::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("runOneIteration")
    runOneIteration.invoke(workDispatcher)

    // then
    verify(metrics).addCount(FAULT, 1)
    verify(metrics).addProperty(EXCEPTION, "RuntimeException")
}
```

I have also tried variations of throwing the exception in this test, including

```
whenever(serviceFacade.doTheThing(any(), any())).doAnswer { throw RuntimeException(errorMessage) }
```

and

```
whenever(serviceFacade.doTheThing(any(), any())).doThrow(RuntimeException(errorMessage))
```

Even if I add a println statement that verifies the exception is a runtime exception, after the log message, the exception prints but it still gives me the following result:

```
[junit] Testcase: handleRuntimeException(com.abc.def.packageName.WorkDispatcherTest):   FAILED
[junit] Expected exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Expected exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Comment: Are you actually invoking `tryToDoTheThing` method from within your test?

Comment: runOneIteration.invoke(workDispatcher) will call it. It's a private method so it can't be called directly.